# Is it possible to remove empty lines in oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Our problem is probably regarding already added values in one of the tables in oracle db version 12.1.0

In CMS we are seeing that the values are without empty rows:

[image: CMS field with data PICTURE]

But when we copy this text and paste it in notepad for example, we got empty row (line breaks, blank row), after every line:

[image: Result after pasting PICTURE]

So, at this point, we are heading to a problem with data imported to the database. The data type of that field is VARCHAR 2000, we have around 10 000 records already in that table and half of them include these empty rows after pasting. Is there any chance that we can remove these empty lines in that column?

Comment: Please check if it's an issue with UNIX vs. DOS line breaks.

Comment: Everything is setup and tested on Windows Server 2012 and Windows 10. We already made tests with Win7 and Server2016 environment - still problem exists.

Comment: can you please provide the result of `dump(column_name)`?

Comment: This is the result with charset: https://pastebin.com/T6HK9tFm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in your dump that there is a sequence: 13,13,10 which is Carriage return, Carriage return + Line Feed.

https://www.petefreitag.com/item/863.cfm

If you replace 13,13,10 by 13,10 you should get the desired results.

```
 replace(column_name,chr(13)||chr(13)||chr(10),chr(13)||chr(10))
```

Comment: Wow, thank you man, that worked flawlessly. If you ever come to Bulgaria, just give me PM , you have one rakia from our department.